# custom_hooks of gitlab in post-receive, ssh to another server

Tags: git, ssh, server, hook, gitlab

I want to add gitlab `custom_hooks` in `post-receive`.

I `ssh`d to another server; I have added the content of `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` on another server, and the `git` user can login without entering a password at the terminal.

When I push, the `post-receive` can be triggered, but it cannot `ssh` to the server.

Does anyone have any idea about the difference between the two types of ssh, or any other suggestions?

---

Solved.
The gitlab is installed via docker, so the git user which execute post-receive is user of gitlab docker. After enter gitlab docker and get the right `id_rsa.pub` to another server, the problem solved.
Thank all and specially @vonc.

Comment: Isn't post-receive already on the server?

Comment: @MadPhysicist post-receive is on the server of gitlab, but I need to login to another server to pull the newest update.

Comment: Nice catch.I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> post-receive can be trigger, but cannot ssh to the server

Simply replace your ssh command by ssh debug commands in the `post-receive` script:

- first add an `id -a` and `echo $HOME` in order to double-check who is actually executing the script, and with which `$HOME` (since `ssh` would seek `id_rsa` in `$HOME/.ssh`)
- then add an `ssh -Tv xxx@server.yyy` in order to display debug information about the failed ssh connection.

That should give you clues about the "two types of ssh".

As the OP found out, this was because the wrong user was in play:

> The gitlab is installed via docker, so the `git` user which executes `post-receive` is user of gitlab docker.
>   After entering gitlab docker and get the right `id_rsa.pub` to another server, the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and editing! the user is git, but the uid is the same as another user, which is different with the git user on terminal. The home are both /home/git, and when ssh, both will "Offering RSA public key: /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa" as the debug information show, then on terminal it will success, but in post-receive, it will "Authentications that can continue: publickey,password", then eventually fail.

Comment: @vinzid "but the uid is the same as another user, which is different with the git user on terminal": that seems fishy, and should be sorted out first.